# Is there a way to calculate how high the water will go?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, fluid-statics, density

Calculate how high the pump pumps water into the reservoir to fill it to 68O hl. When filling the reservoir, there will be a work done of 9MJ. (ρ = 1000 kg / m2)

I am having a real hard time with this one :/

Comment: hl = hectolitres? $1000kg/m^3$?

Comment: yes aand yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. Convert volume from 68O hl (hectolitres) to cubic metres. (**V**)
2. Then calculate the mass of this volume (using ρ). (**M**)
3. Then calculate how much work it takes to lift (**M**) kg of water by 1 m. (**W**)
4. Finally, use **W** t0 calculate the distance you would need to raise **M** in order to do 9MJ of work. (**D**).

And that will be your answer...

Comment: Thank you so much!